# How can I decrease mod-security severity?

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, mod-security

Actually the module blocks calls with "notice" level. How can I decrease the severity level and take it to "warning"?

Comment: Can you rephrase your question and add more details (perhaps with log files showing the issue)? Is there a specify rule that is giving you a notice level alert? What do you "decrease" security from notice to warning? Surely that's an increase in security?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `SecDebugLogLevel` value in whitelist.conf:

> 0: No logging
>
> 1: errors
>
> 2: warnings
>
> 3: notices
>
> 4: details of how transactions are handled
>
> 5: as above, but including information about each piece of information
>   handled
>
> 6: log everything

more informations : http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/analyzing-mod-security-logs/